# ffmpeg failed to drawbox and set volume

Tags: ffmpeg

I don't know what is wrong in my command with ffmpeg.
Lets say I have a video and I want to make a black screen with muted audio between 20-30 seconds. So what I wrote is:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]trim=0:20[0v];[0:a]atrim=0:20[0a];[0:v]trim=20:30,drawbox=color=black:t=fill[1v];[0:a]atrim=20:30,volume=0[1a];[0:v]trim=30:60[2v];[0:a]atrim=30:60[2a];[0v][1v][2v]concat=n=3:v=1:a=0[outv];[0a][1a][2a]concat=n=3:v=0:a=1[outa]" -map [outv] -map [outa] output.mp4
```

Now, I expect to have a video with 1 min length where the seconds between 20 & 30 are muted with black screen, but what I got is:

```
20 sec correct
20 sec freezing video with no audio
40 sec black video with no audio
30 sec correct
```

Can anyone help and tell me what is wrong in the command line?

Answer (score 1):

add setpts:

```
ffmpeg -i "input 2.mp4" -filter_complex "
[0:v] trim=0:20[0v];
[0:a]atrim=0:20[0a];
[0:v] trim=20:30, setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,drawbox=color=black:t=fill[1v];
[0:a]atrim=20:30,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS,volume=0[1a];
[0:v] trim=30:60, setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[2v];
[0:a]atrim=30:60,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[2a];
[0v][0a][1v][1a][2v][2a]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[outv][outa]
" -map [outv] -map [outa] output.mp4
```